# DNS servers provided by dhcp are automatically routed to local MAC address

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, freebsd, route

On my freebsd, when ip and network conf is given by the dhcp, these routes are added for unknown reason :

```
192.168.138.6      54:a0:xx:xx:xx:xx  UHS    re0_vlan100
192.168.138.5      54:a0:xx:xx:xx:xx  UHS    re0_vlan100
```

The mac address is the one of my computer interface, and the IPs are for the local DNS servers :

```
root@ox2:~ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
domain localhost.localdomain
nameserver 192.168.138.6
nameserver 192.168.138.5
nameserver 208.67.222.222 (opendns manually added)
nameserver 8.8.8.8 (google dns manually added)
```

Which are given by dhcp :

```
lease {
   interface "re0_vlan100";
   fixed-address 172.17.4.92;
   option subnet-mask 255.255.0.0;
   option routers 172.17.0.1;
   option domain-name-servers 192.168.138.6,192.168.138.5;
   option broadcast-address 172.17.255.255;
   option dhcp-lease-time 172800;
   option dhcp-message-type 5;
   option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.138.5;
   renew 3 2017/9/27 10:27:40;
   rebind 4 2017/9/28 04:27:40;
   expire 4 2017/9/28 10:27:40;
}
```

Because of these routes, querying the defaults dns fails. Deleting the routes fix the problem, until the lease is renewed...

Where do these routes come from ? And how do I stop them ?

I've tried on several networks with completely different isp/router, this happens every time.

Answer (score 0):

The S designation (as part of the UHS in your example) means that it is manually added to the routing table.  Could be that these entries are in your /etc/iproute2/ files?
If that doesn't show anything, run a grep to find the files they exist in by:

```
grep -R "192.168.138.5" /etc
```